# geo location not working in mozilla 25 - not working in secured network - https

Tags: html, geolocation

geo location is not working in mozilla 25 dont know what is the reason behind this .

Am i doing anything wrong ? i am using this api first time so please help me to find what i am doing wrong :

here is my code

```
$(window).load(function() {

        if($("#zipcode").val() == ""){
            getLocation();
        }

});

function setZipCode(position){
    var ajaxObj = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $googleMapAPI,
        data: {"latlng":position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude,"sensor":"true"}
    });
    ajaxObj.done(function(response){
        for(var loop=0;loop<response.results[0].address_components.length;loop++){
            if(response.results[0].address_components[loop].types == "postal_code"){
                $("#zipcode").val(response.results[0].address_components[loop].long_name);
            }
        }
    });
}

function getLocation(){
    // Call the geolocation script only when zipcode is not passed by marketing page
    if(navigator.geolocation && $("#zipcode").val()==""){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setZipCode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You ever get this working?  I saw on the Mozilla bug site that someone said you could run Firefox in administrator mode on Windows to get it to work.  Not a good answer - my web-based users aren't going to know that and will think the app is broken.  Works like a champ on other browsers.